# Lagrange Multipliers Dilemma

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

In the problem

$f(x,y) = xy$ and $g(x, y) = x^2 + 9y^2 = 18$

I get

$y = 2λx$, $x = 18λy$ and $x^2 + 9y^2 = 18$ (the constraint).

All is fine, but I feel like I'll get two different answers depending on what my first step is.

I could do $y = 2λ(18λy) $
or I could do $x = 18λ(2λx)$

Almost identical. But...

$y = 36λ^2y$, $y - 36λ^2y = 0$, $y(1-36λ^2) y = 0$ or $λ = \pm1/6$.

or

$x = 36λ^2x$, $x - 36λ^2x = 0$, $x(1-36λ^2) = 0$ where $x = 0$ or $λ =\pm 1/6$.

Which component is zero flips!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Notice that $x=0\implies y=0$ from the first equation, and $y=0\implies x=0$ from the second equation, so you can eliminate these possibilities since (0,0) is not on the constraint.

Comment: The critical point is in a point $(0,y,z)$ iff it is in a point $(0,0,z)$. Similarly, it is in the point $(x,0,z)$ iff it is in a point $(0,0,z)$. Observe that since $y_c=2\lambda x_c$ and $x_c=18\lambda y_c$, you have that $x_c=0\iff y_c=0$, which gives that you can't have neither $x_c=0$ nor $y_c=0$, since that would contradict $x^2+9y^2=18$. This gives $\lambda=\pm \frac{1}{6}$.